# iPhone using iAd outside USA

Tags: iphone, iad

Is it all right for non-US based developers to use iAd in their apps?

I have read somewhere, some time ago, that iAd was just for US-based developers and that if you develop some app using iAds, adds won't show when the customer is using a device outside the US.

What is the truth behind it?

thanks.

Comment: Havent actually used iAds in an app, but quite sure I've seen european apps using it. Was announced to be in europe last year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Apple's website](http://developer.apple.com/iad/), "iAd advertisements are currently being served to apps on the U.S., U.K., Germany, Italy, Spain, France, and Japan App Stores."

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: So, but in theory all developers, even those not US-Based can use it, but the ads will just be served if a user is on one of these countries, right?